# How can I prevent PRs from changing my CI configuration?

Tags: security, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

We have an open source project in GitHub. And we use Azure DevOps pipelines for our CI.

We publish our artefacts to S3 and Maven after successful tests, so all the credentials are stored as secret variables.

It's nice that `export` and `echo $top_secret` are conveniently obfuscated with ***, but unfortunately literally any user on GitHub can create a pull request against our repo, and as part of the changes, they can edit our azure-pipelines.yml and call a curl (or similar) to read the credentials from environmental variables and send them to their own server.

In other CI providers (Travis CI) secret variables are not accessible from PR branches.

How can I prevent PRs from touching my CI configuration file and do anything with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I prevent PRs from touching my CI configuration file and do anything with it?

You CI configuration file is save in the GitHub open source and you want to restrict users from changing this file, right? Since we cannot set file permission in the GitHub. we cannot prevent PRs from touching your CI configuration file.

As a workaround, we could create classic editor pipeline in the Azure DevOps and set the CI Trigger, such as below. If users do not have permission to change the build definition, they cannot change your CI build definition.

[image]

**Update1**

[image]

Comment: You mean create another pipeline governed by another yml file that fails if someone is committing into azure-pipelines.yml? But they can change that too!

Comment: Create classic editor pipeline instead of YAML build pipeline in the Azure DevOps, it will not create azure-pipeline.yml in the repo. Check the update1

Comment: OK thanks, I tried and with the classic editor and I finally managed to have a pipeline which is not persisted within the repo as a file. But now I can't help but thinking holding CI configurations in-repo is a terrible idea all together: beside security,  it's also inconvenient because when I change something I always need to change it in all the branches!

Comment: Hi @sscarduzio, If this answer is helpful, would you please accept it as the answer? So it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread. Thanks. Have a nice day. :)

Comment: yeah you are right, done! I have a question. From you username it looks you work at MSFT: do you plan to sunset the "classic" editor in the future? For how long can I rely on this solution?

Comment: You could check [Azure DevOps Feature Timeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/features-timeline) to get the Azure DevOps updates, I can't find any information about disabling the classic editor, you can use it with confidence